# are crown molding corner blocks a good idea

Tags: trim

This will be my first time at installing crown molding.  I see that I have option of installing crown molding with corner blocks which I can buy in various styles and I think look nice.  It seems that this option adds cost to the job but means i wont have to be doing any miter cuts or cope any joints which will speed up the job for me as a newbie.  Aside from additional cost of purchasing the corner blocks are they any downsides to using corner blocks vs. not using them and going through and doing all the mitering and cope cuts?

thx for any advice

Comment: One potential disadvantage is they can make things difficult if the room isn't perfectly square. Other than that I got nothin'.

Comment: The corner blocks may actually be more difficult to install because you would have to trim them to fit corners that are not perfectly square. Making coping cuts may actually be the easier, and cheaper route.

Comment: If you like 'em, go for it! The caulking gun will go a long way toward fixing out of square corners. (As would digging out a bit of the drywall compound behind.)

Answer (score 3):

The downsides I can think of are:

1. Cost
2. More seams
3. Not learning how do it yourself
4. If the corners aren't square - and they are usually not, they will be difficult to install.

The upside is obviously speed and ease of install.

Comment: OK.  thx for advice all